# c++ std::map get element with highest key below X?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, stdmap

Given a C++ map (or multimap) where the key is an integer, is it possible using STL to request the range of elements whose key is the largest number below a given number?

So if I had:

```
map = {{1,'x'}, {2, 'g'}, {3, 'n'}, {3, 'm'}, {4, 'z'}, {5, 'a'}}
```

and I want to find the element(s) just before 4, it would return:

```
{{3, 'n'}, {3, 'm'}}
```

(I'm more interested in `std::map` but kept the question general for `std::multimap` too).

Comment: sounds like you want [`std::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound)

Comment: @Bathsheba Why delete? The answer is fine, just put a disclaimer or fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `lower_bound()` to find the first element after the ones you want, then decrement the iterator and use `equal_range()` to access all the elements matching that one:

### Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
   std::multimap<int, char> const
       m{{1,'x'}, {2,'g'}, {3,'n'}, {3,'m'}, {4,'z'}, {5 'a'}};

   auto i = m.lower_bound(4);
   if (i == m.begin()) {
       std::cerr << "No elements less than 4 were found\n";
   } else {
       --i;
       auto const range = m.equal_range(i->first);
       for (auto j = range.first;  j != range.second;  ++j)
           std::cout << j->first << ", " << j->second << '\n';
   }
}
```

### Output

```
3, n
3, m
```

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for your map's [upper_bound()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/upper_bound/) method.

This will actually return the iterator to the first key in the map that's larger than the passed in value.

Presuming you did not get back the `begin()` value (indicating that there are no keys in the map that meets your criteria), just decrement the returned iterator.

Comment: You omitted the part where you use `equal_range` to get all the elements with that key (the example in the question implies a multimap).

Answer (score 4):

Given a number `N`, use `std::map::upper_bound(N-1)`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
   std::map<int, char> am = {{1,'x'}, {2, 'g'}, {3, 'm'}, {4, 'z'}, {5, 'a'}};
   auto iter = am.upper_bound(3);
   if ( iter != am.begin() )
   {
      --iter;
      std::cout << iter->first << ", " << iter->second << std::endl;
   }
}
```

Output:

```
3, m
```